# I need a c# function to determine the combinations of n max integers. Thanks

Tags: c#, .net, combinations, permutation

Unlike other examples that provide combinations of n for k values, I have an array of n and I need a combination of all values from 0 - n.  For example:

If I have an array of 5,8,3,4,9 the function would return:

0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,1
...
1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,2
...
5,8,3,4,9

I can accomplish this using a process to find the combinations of a max of n for k values, but it provides too many combinations (many of these combinations are invalid that I have to throw out):

```
private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetCombinations<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, int length) where T : IComparable
        {
            if (length == 1) return list.Select(t => new T[] { t });
            return GetCombinations(list, length - 1)
                .SelectMany(t => list.Where(o => o.CompareTo(t.Last()) >= 0),
                    (t1, t2) => t1.Concat(new T[] { t2 }));
        }
```

0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,1
...
9,9,9,9,9

Comment: Show what you have done so far.

Comment: @DavidG No.  In the case of 5,8,3,4,9 - I need combinations of 0-5,0-8,0-3,0-4,0-9.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Either way, you need to show us what you have tried so far, this isn't a code writing service I'm afraid.

Comment: If I just find the number of combinations of n for k, I end up with too many combinations.  It provides combinations all the way up 9,9,9,9,9.  I need to go from 0,0,0,0,0 to 5,8,3,4,9 with all the variations within.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for consideration.  Just thought someone had come across this problem already and solved it.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is going to work with just `IComparable<T>`. For example, if using strings for your values, what would be the expected output from your combinations of `{ "Tom", "Dick", "Harry" }` be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an implementation that would work for numeric types:

```
public static IEnumerable<T[]> Combinations<T>(T[] values) where T: INumber<T>
{
    var current = new T[values.Length];

    do
    {
        yield return current.ToArray();
    }
    while (increment());

    bool increment()
    {
        for (int index = current.Length - 1; index >= 0; --index)
        {
            if (++current[index] <= values[index])
                return true;

            current[index] = default!;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var array = new [] { 5, 8, 3, 4, 9 };

    foreach (var combination in Combinations(array))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", combination));
    }
}
```

However, your test code is using `IComparable` - I can't see how that would work with non-numeric `IComparable` types such as `string` and `DateTime`.

For example, what would it mean for an input array of `{"Tom", "Dick", "Harry"}` ?